# ¿Como puedo dividir un arreglo en N partes con reduce?

Tags: javascript, reduce

Tengo este array de objetos:

> let dataArray = [
> {
> id: 1,
> nombre: "prueba 1"
> },
> {
> id: 2,
> nombre: "prueba 2"
> },
> {
> id: 3,
> nombre: "prueba 3"
> },
> {
> id: 4,
> nombre: "prueba 4"
> },
> {
> id: 5,
> nombre: "prueba 5"
> },
> {
> id: 6,
> nombre: "prueba 6"
> },
> {
> id: 7,
> nombre: "prueba 7"
> },
> {
> id: 8,
> nombre: "prueba 8"
> },
> {
> id: 9,
> nombre: "prueba 9"
> },
> {
> id: 10,
> nombre: "prueba 10"
> }
> ];

Y quisiera dividirlo en **n** partes con la función de **reduce**, ya que solo encontré una solución con el ciclo **for** y que a mí parece esta funcionando correctamente, pero si habría otra forma seria genial:

Esta forma es con el **for**:

```
let numElement = 3;

for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i += numElement) {
    console.log(i);
    let parte = dataArray.slice(i, i + numElement);
    dataFormateada.push(parte);
}
```

Y me da como resultado:

> let resultado =       [
> [
> {
> id: 1,
> nombre: "prueba 1"
> },
> {
> id: 2,
> nombre: "prueba 2"
> },
> {
> id: 3,
> nombre: "prueba 3"
> }
> ],
> [
> {
> id: 4,
> nombre: "prueba 4"
> },
> {
> id: 5,
> nombre: "prueba 5"
> },
> {
> id: 6,
> nombre: "prueba 6"
> }
> ],
> [
> {
> id: 7,
> nombre: "prueba 7"
> },
> {
> id: 8,
> nombre: "prueba 8"
> },
> {
> id: 9,
> nombre: "prueba 9"
> }
> ],
> [
> {
> id: 10,
> nombre: "prueba 10"
> }
> ]
> ];

Y esto es el código que realice con **reduce**, pero no salio el resultado que esperaba.

```
const dataFormateada = dataArray.reduce((ac, _, i, data) => { 
       if (i < numElement) { 
          let value = data.slice(i, numElement); 
          ac.push(value); 
       } 
       return ac;
 }, []);
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser con `reduce`? ¿Qué has intentado / investigado? ¿Pretendes qué lo hagan por ti? Muestra un [mcve] de lo que has intentado hacer con `reduce`. Podrías repasar [ask]. Saludos

Comment: He intentado de esta forma:  

> const dataFormateada = dataArray.reduce((ac, _, i, data) => {
    if (i < numElement) {
     let value = data.slice(i, numElement);
     ac.push(value);
    }

    return ac;
   }, []);

Pero no me trae la respuesta que deseo.

Comment: Agrega eso en la pregunta por favor.